Call center configuration with issabelpbx
I have configured a call center with issabel pbx with 4 agents I have configured the queues, the inbound and outbound routes and the trunks but the problem I have is that when I call the number of my call center, the agents do not receive the call
any help would be appreciated, Thank you in advance
